# Running search and replace with sed via python subprocess results in unviewable characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, sed, subprocess, python-3.5

Given the file `/tmp/hi` with content: `bali=${hi`

and running the command on it `sed -i -E 's/(^|[^.])hi/\1bi/g' /tmp/hi`

results in the following content in `bali=${bi` as expected.

However, running the sed command inside python3.5  subprocess:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run("sed -i -E 's/(^|[^.])hi/\1bi/g' /tmp/hi", shell=True)
```

results in the following content:  [image]

inspected the file in `vi` and it shows: `bali=$^Abi`

Why does it happen and how to achieve the same file content using python3.5 subprocess?

Comment: Why would you use `sed` for this anyway? Python's `re` is both more versatile and obviously easier to control from Python code than `sed` in a subprocess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the `\1` is being interpreted by Python. You need to use raw string syntax (`r"some \1 string with escape sequences"`) if you want to use escape sequences without having to escape them:

```
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print("sed -i -E 's/(^|[^.])hi/\1bi/g' /tmp/hi")
sed -i -E 's/(^|[^.])hi/bi/g' /tmp/hi
>>> print(r"sed -i -E 's/(^|[^.])hi/\1bi/g' /tmp/hi")
sed -i -E 's/(^|[^.])hi/\1bi/g' /tmp/hi
```